# Ejb injection in web service when no ejb instance is available in the pool

Tags: ejb, websphere, ejb-3.0, websphere-8

I want to know what will happen when there are no ejbs available in the pool and a client is trying to access a web service which uses the ejb.

We are receiving a NPE at the line where the ejb instance is used to call a method. Unfortunately I do not have access to the logs right now and I am trying to figure out what is wrong. So I am thinking in all possible ways and this question spawned in my head.

Can anyone please tell me?

What I think is, the web service will not be initialized until an ejb instance is available in the pool. So In this case the request will be queued and after sometime the client will receive a timeout error or appropriate message. Am I right?

P.S
BTW, if it makes any difference, I am injecting the ejb using @EJB annotation.

Comment: What do you mean by "web service"?  JAX-RS classes in particular are not automatically eligible for Java EE injection.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a reference to a SLSB the initialization is just a proxy, no instance is needed.
At runtime the invocation try to get an instance from the pool, if there are all instances busy it will be blocked for a while (5sec by default) and throw an Exception in case of timeout, otherwise just continue.
If you get a NPE this seems to me a different issue where you can't get a reference.
A stateful bean is different, but I think you don't use that.

I think it should be the same no matter which container you use.

Comment: Where did the "5sec by default" come from?  As far as I know, WebSphere Application Server will create new instances as needed by default.

Comment: JBoss/WildFly will use a StrictMaxPool to prevent from too many SLSB instances. In general this is not a problem and prevent from re-create the instances. The pool setting can override that parameters

Comment: The question is tagged "websphere" and "websphere-8", so I don't think the behavior on JBoss/WildFly is relevant here.

Comment: It is possible to enforce a max pool size in WebSphere, though the default timeout is 5 minutes or transaction timeout (default 2 minutes), which ever is less. Does not sound like the issue here though.

If the reference is null, that means the server process is unaware that the field needs to be injected.  I would check that your web.xml is version 2.5 or greater and that it does not contain metadata-complete="true".  Also, ensure that the class javax.ejb.EJB is not packaged with your application.